# Validation inside Pojo

Tags: java

This is more of a design question.

I have a POJO class defined like,

```
class MyPOJO {  
    private String memberVariable;  
    MyPOJO(String memberVariable) {  
      validate(memberVariable);
      this.memberVariable = memberVariable;
    }  
}
```

My question is how far can we go while validating the memberVariable constructor parameter. Is the following validate method impl acceptable,

```
private validate(final String memberVariable) {
    Validate.isNotNull(memberVariable); // this is basic check.
    Validate.isTrue(memberVariable.indexOf(" ") == -1); //again a basic check.
    List<String> validValues = DBFactory.getDB().getValidValues();
    Validate.isTrue(validValues.contains(memberVariable)); // checks if the memberVariable value is present in db.
}
```

The argument behind doing strict checks in the constructor of the POJO is that we can be sure that a MyPOJO instance will never be created with any random memberVariable.
My question is whether this is a good design scheme? or should the validation logic be pulled out of POJO all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No input validation is part of the POJO. This way you can guarantee that the created instance are correct. In general this is called [Design-by-Contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075719/a-good-design-by-contract-library-for-java).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes. Why not?

Long answer: Yes, but...

1. What do you plan to do if it fails validation? What kind of exception will you throw?
2. It appears you can condense all of this into the check for valid values, since there wont' be null or spaced values in valid values (I presume).

Comment: I guess the OP is using the apache library for validation check, which if I remember correctly throws an illegal argument exception.

Comment: @Scorpion In commons-lang 3, they changed notNull to throw a NullPointerException for virtually no reason (the Jira issue "fixed" had been closed as WON'T FIX for a long time)  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-52?

Comment: 1. IllegalArgumentException (a runtime exception). Is it ok for the client to not know that an exception will be thrown at *runtime* if the value that is provided is NOT in the list. Ofcourse we can document it but if the client doesn't know the list of values how can he instantiate the pojo in the first place. How to unit test this thing?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is good. If an object cannot be instantiated with illegal arguments it always makes sense to throw an illegal argument exception. This also helps you keep your object immutable.