# Should callers check validity of arguments before calling constructor?

Tags: java, oop, coding-style

I have been reading a lot about TDD and clean code recently so I start working on a simple project that puts these to use and I have come up against something that I am really not sure what the best approach to take is.

I have a class that takes a Java `File` object as a parameter, the expectation is that this `File` object must be a directory and must begin with a certain prefix.  My first pass through involved doing checks on the `File` object before calling the constructor, i.e. checking that it is a directory and checking that the name is valid.  But I don't like that it is the caller that is specifying what makes it valid and particularly what the valid prefix is, I think this logic should be placed in the class itself.

I could do this checking in the constructor and throw an exception if it is not valid, but given the nature of the problem, if I am iterating over a list of `File`s then it is fully expected that some of them won't be 'valid' (i.e. they will be files rather than directories) so is throwing an `Exception` really warranted?

```
public MyObject(File directory) {
    if (!directory.isDirectory()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be a directory");
    }
    if (!directory.getName().startsWith("Prefix")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must start with Prefix");
    }
    ....
}
```

I thought about maybe adding a Factory method to create the objects and returning null if the `File` is invalid.

```
public static MyObject createMyObject(File directory) {
    if (!directory.isDirectory() || !directory.getName().startsWith("Prefix")) {
        return null;
    }
    return new MyObject(directory);
}
```

Alternatively I thought about adding a static method to the class that validates the File for the caller before calling the constructor.

```
public static boolean isValid(File directory) {
    return directory.isDirectory() && directory.getName().startsWith("Prefix");
}

if (MyObject.isValid(directory)) {
    MyObject object = new MyObject(directory);
}
```

So in terms of clean code and all the OOP principles (such as single responsibility, coupling etc.) which would be the preferred way of doing this?

**UPDATE:**

Having read some of the answers that have been posted already I started thinking about another possibility that would be applicable to only my current situation rather than generically as my question was really about.

As part of my calling code I have a path from the filesystem and I am listing all files in that directory and it is each file that I am then passing to the MyObject constructor whether it is valid or not.  I could pass a `FileFilter` to the method `listFiles` that ensures that listFiles only returns valid directories.  The `FileFilter` could be declared within MyObject:

```
public static FileFilter getFilter() {
    return new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File path) {
            return path.isDirectory() && path.getName().startsWith("Prefix");
        }
    };
}
```

If my constructor threw an exception then it would really be an exceptional situation because the expectation is that it is only being passed valid directories.  Doing this would mean that I could remove the need for a checked exception from constructor/factory since any exception would indicate a bug somewhere rather than expected behaviour.  But it still leaves the question of whether to put it in a constructor or a factory method.

Comment: To me, the third one would be preferable. Shorter and you can use it with a number of files. Also you don't need to return a new object from the isValid method, and you create the object only if isValid returns true from another part of your code. This is good as it separates functionalities.

Comment: @AliAlamiri In terms of clean code that is my preference because reading it makes the most sense, i.e. it is clear to the reader what is happening. I just can't decide if I like the fact that the caller has to be aware that he should call isValid first.

Comment: Why not pass the file to the constructor and check there if the file isValid. This hides the checking from the caller as you construct objects and have the constructor check the files being passed?

Comment: @AliAlamiri yes that is one of the options, but I am just wondering about the best practice for throwing exceptions within a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be my preference to offer the combination of a constructor that validates and throws an exception when the argument given does not fullfill its contract supplemented by the `static boolean isValid()` validation method.

Used in a loop the validation method offers a nice, readable way of constructing valid objects, while the constructor makes sure non-validated uses are handled by throwing an exception when needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static MyObject createMyObject(File directory) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    if (!directory.isDirectory() || !directory.getName().startsWith("Prefix")) {
        return throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid parameters")";
    }
    return new MyObject(directory);
}
```

This is one of the option which is a mix of two of your suggested options. Uses Factory method and also validates the pre-conditions which is what factory methods are good at doing. So IMO this can be a nice option.

> **Why not option 2 as it is:**
>   Because returning `nulls` is a bad option when you can throw exceptions to warn the user that some pre-conditions were not met.

**UPDATE:**
This strategy gives guarantee that only an object in valid state will be created. 
Also if you want to mock out the instance of `MyObject` you can make it implement some interface for using Runtime Polymorphism and pass out mock objects around. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: On a separate note for TDD this is a good resource that I used to understand fundamentals for writing testable code http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/

Answer (score 1):

I think where the validation code belongs depends on exactly what the 'MyObject' class represents.

If MyObject performs some operations that would fail if it had a file rather than a directory then I would say it should contain the validation code in its constructor - that makes the class self-contained, and will allow for possible re-use of the class later.

If MyObject is just a container for the file/directory, and there is no directory-specific code in it, then put the validation code inside that class that *does* require a directory rather than a file.

Comment: Keeping the validation code in constructor is discouraged as you are stuck with this behavior while testing and you just want a mock to be passed around, which will not be possible here. as when you try to create a mock with some mock values then those mock values MUST be valid for instantiation to be successful.

Comment: I think checking arguments inside a constructor is fairly standard practice, Joshua Bloch certainly encourages it strongly in Effective Java: "Constructors represent a special case of the principle that you should check the validity of parameters that are to be stored away for later use. It is critical to check the validity of constructor parameters to prevent the construction of an object that violates its class invariants."

Comment: Constructors should contain only assignments and the pre-condition validation should be done by either factory method or factory for the object. http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/ this is a good resource that promotes this methodology.

Comment: I can see the benefit from a testability point of view, but are we really saying that 'new Integer("not a number")' should run without any errors?

Comment: No. In that case the only way to get an instance of integer is to use the factory method or factory class.

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

From a coding perspective, the simplest and cleanest approach is the exploding (unchdcked) constructor. If there is a reasonable expectation that the caller would and should only pass directories in, then go with that.

If there is a reasonable expectation that the caller may pass in non-directories, then you have two choices:

1. If the caller can deal with the situation, have the constructor throw a *checked* exception
2. If the caller can not deal with an exception, you can have your class "do nothing" if the caller invokes a method - basically ignoring all requests to "do" something if the File passed to the constructor is not a directory.

Comment: So the idea is that given a path in the filesystem the code will iterate over its contents and create a list of all the directories with the given prefix. So it is perfectly reasonable to expect that some of the contents won't be valid, so I wouldn't want these files/directories added to the list.  I just wasn't sure about adding exceptions to a constructor or whether it is better to go with a Factory.

Comment: Factory or not, you need to decide who is going to handle the problem. Once you figure that out, the approach should be obvious. Note that a factory doesn't help in this case - you're still left with the same choices, just moved to a different method. A factory is only useful if you need to do something with the object after its constructed (to avoid the "letting `this` escape" problem when `this` is passed to a method from within the constructor).

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Design-by-Contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075719/a-good-design-by-contract-library-for-java) and there are libraries for, to help you with checking the incoming arguments.