# Best way to structure with many validating methods

Tags: java, design-patterns

Here is my code

```
public class Validator {
private String message = "ok";

public String mainValidate(String value) {
    if(!isAccept1()) {
        message = "fail1";
        return message;
    }

    if(!isAccept2()) {
        message = "fail2";
        return message;
    }

    if(!isAccept3()) {
        message = "fail3";
        return message;
    }
    return message;
}

public boolean isAccept1() {}

public boolean isAccept2() {}

public boolean isAccept3() {}
```

Requirement is: If the code meet any error, return message immediately.
As you can see, with current code, I repeat myself very much.
How can I structure the code and still keep requirement. If any error occur, the code skip other validate and return error message

Many thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a very broad topic which is mostley opinion based. I recommend to use a way that works for you and your application.

Comment: You already return imemdiately. I did not understand what you try to achieve here.

Comment: Can you recommend a way for this case?

Comment: Shouldn't this belongs to [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) forum ?
Please refer to this [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/234617/167527)

Comment: You could put all checks in one method and just call the one method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the actions / messages in a map and iterate over it:

```
private static final Map<Predicate<String>, String> VALIDATIONS = new LinkedHashMap<> ();

static {
  VALIDATIONS.put(Validator::isAccept1, "fail1");
  VALIDATIONS.put(Validator::isAccept2, "fail2");
  //etc.
}

public String mainValidate(String value) {
  for (Entry<Predicate<String>, String> v : VALIDATIONS.entrySet()) {
    Predicate<String> validator = v.getKey();
    String errorMsg = v.getValue();
    if (!validator.test(value)) return errorMsg;
  }
  return "ok";
}

public static boolean isAccept1(String value) { return /* ... */; }
```

Comment: I will try your solution. It is something new to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can put all the checks in one method:

```
public String mainValidate(String value) {
    String message = isAccept();
    if(!message.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
        return message;
    }
}

private String isAccept() {
    String returnString = "ok";
    //check1 - change returnString to whatever message if check fails
    //check2 - change returnString to whatever message if check fails
    //check3 - change returnString to whatever message if check fails
    //etc...
    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: How about using **Decorator Pattern** for those different types of validations? I think that would be easier when another new type of validations come in future.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as:

- [Design by Contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
- or [Precondition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition)
- or [Method Argument Validation](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=5)

See also [A good Design-by-Contract library for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075719/a-good-design-by-contract-library-for-java)