# Use AssertJ in Spring Boot production code

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, assertj

Is it possible to use AssertJ in Spring Boot production code ?
I managed to use it in unit test, but 'import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;' could not be resolved in java file of src/main/java folder even though I tried to fix it by changing build path and change the  of junit.
Or it is a bad practice to use AssertJ in production code ?

Comment: AssertJ is not meant to be used in production, but nothing prevents you to do so. If the productive code cannot resolve the AssertJ package, you might need to change the scope of the AssertJ dependency in your dependency management tool. What kind of use case are you trying to address with AssertJ in production code?

Comment: To throw exception when there is invalid input. I guess I know the mistake I made, it should be the scope of 'starter-test' which include the AssertJ instead of 'junit'. It's fine now, I change to Spring Boot Assertion.

Comment: FYI: [A good Design-by-Contract library for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1075719/4506703)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AssertJ is not designed to be used in production code. In case of input validation with a Spring Boot application, [`Assert`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Assert.html) from the Spring Framework, [`Validate`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html) from Apache Commons Lang, or [`Preconditions`](https://guava.dev/releases/31.0.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) from Google Guava may be good alternatives.

Comment: When you say "AssertJ is not designed to be used in production code" is there any design decision in particular that makes it unsuitable for production use? Personally I find the API very elegant to work with, also for `Preconditions` like checks.

Comment: Nothing specific prevents using AssertJ in production code. However, production code is not the main focus of the library, so production aspects have not been closely scrutinized, such as security or scaling.